# What happens if I add an unsigned int to a negative int and the arithmetic result is positive?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, expression, language-lawyer

When I was about to execute the following code I thought the signed int i would be converted to unsigned and the result would be some big positive number but the result was 2

```
int main()
{
    unsigned u = 10; int i = -8;
    std::cout << u + i << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 10-8=2, why did you expect a big number?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When performing addition, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands, which state ([[expr]/11.5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#11.5.3)):

> - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand,
>     the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of
>     the operand with unsigned integer type.

So `-8` is converted to an unsigned number. Which according to [[conv.integral]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral#2) is as follows:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least
>   unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>   where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).

That translates our number to `(MAX_UINT + 1) - 8`. Now, since unsigned addition is modular 2<sup>n</sup> ([[basic.fundamental]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.fundamental#4)):

> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.

The result must be `(MAX_UINT + 1) - 8 + 10` modulo `MAX_UINT + 1`, and that is just `2`.